# combine enumeration of chapters

Tags: macros, chapters

at the beginning of one part of my document I've got a tabular with some values and in the chapters afterwards I'll explain them. 
Some values need to be combined; so the chapters have to be enumerated eg. that way:

```
1. A
2. B
3. - 5. C
6. - 7. D
8. E
```

I think of something like defining an alternate chapter-command `\chapterA`.

For instance:

```
\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\chapterA{3}{C} % combine 3 values
\chapterA{2}{D} % combine 2 values
\chapter{E}
```

What does this command have to look like?

I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36756/combine-two-items-in-an-enumerated-list) but couldn't manage to apply it to the `\chapter` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec); the command `\standardchapter` produces a "normal" heading; `\combinedchapter` produces a heading in each the numbering has the form `<number>.-- <number>+#1`, where `#1` is the integer in the mandatory argument:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand\standardchapter{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
}
\newcommand\combinedchapter[1]{%
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.--\,\number\numexpr\thechapter+#1\relax.\addtocounter{chapter}{#1}}{1em}{}
}

\begin{document}

\let\cleardoublepage\relax% just for the example

\standardchapter
\chapter{A}
\chapter{B}
\combinedchapter{2}
\chapter{C}
\combinedchapter{3}
\chapter{D}
\standardchapter
\chapter{E}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following example defines `\chapterA` with a range as chapter number. Also chapters inside the appendix are supported. Because of the longer numbers, the table of contents is adjusted accordingly.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\let\savedthechapter\thechapter
\let\orgchapter\chapter
\renewcommand*{\chapter}{%
  \let\thechapter\savedthechapter
  \orgchapter
}
\newcommand*{\chapterA}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{chapter}%
  \edef\thechapterauxA{\savedthechapter}%
  \addtocounter{chapter}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
  \edef\thechapterauxB{\savedthechapter}%
  \edef\thechapter{\thechapterauxA.--\thechapterauxB}%
  \addtocounter{chapter}{-1}%
  \orgchapter
}

% \appendix changes \thechapter for uppercase letters
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \global\let\savedthechapter\thechapter
}
\makeatother

% patch \l@chapter to get room for the chapter number
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{%
  \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
}{%
  \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
}{}{\errmessage{Patching \string\l@chapter\space failed}}
\patchcmd{\l@section}{{1.5em}}{{3em}}%
  {}{\errmessage{Patching \string\l@section\space failed}}
\patchcmd{\l@subsection}{{3.8em}}{{5.3em}}%
  {}{\errmessage{Patching \string\l@subsection\space failed}}
% analog: subsubsection, paragraph, subparagraph, ...
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter{A}
  \chapter{B}
  \chapterA{3}{C} % combine 3 values
  \chapterA{2}{D} % combine 2 values
  \chapter{E}
  \section{Section}
  \subsection{Subsection}
  \appendix
  \chapter{Appendix 1}
  \chapterA{3}{Appendix 2-4}
  \chapter{Appendix 5}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]